# This version of CLI is only compatible with Angular versions ^14.0.0

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

I got the following error:

```
This version of CLI is only compatible with Angular versions ^14.0.0,
but Angular version 15.0.0 was found instead.

Please visit the link below to find instructions on how to update Angular.
https://update.angular.io/
```

I updated Angular to v15 deleted node_moudels and package-lock.json and still got this error.

`ng v` shows me version is ok.
I also changed my builder back to the default one `"builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser"`

How to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

did you see any issue during compilations? I have the same issue. On my side it happens because issue ngcc...

```
....
....
- @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap [esm2015/esm2015] (git+https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap.git)
- @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap [main/umd] (git+https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap.git)
- ng-bullet [fesm5/esm5] ()
- ng-bullet [esm2015/esm2015] ()
- ng-bullet [esm5/esm5] ()
- ng-bullet [main/umd] ()
Warning: Unable to fully load C:/.../node_modules/ng-bullet/bundles/ng-bullet.umd.js for source-map flattening: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'replace')
Warning: Unable to fully load C:/.../node_modules/ng-bullet/bundles/ng-bullet.umd.js for source-map flattening: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'replace')
Error: Error when flattening the source-map "C:..../node_modules/ng-bullet/bundles/ng-bullet.umd.js.map" for "C:/.../node_modules/ng-bullet/bundles/ng-bullet.umd.js": TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'rawMap')
Encourage the library authors to publish an Ivy distribution.

    ng version:
    Package                         Version
    ---------------------------------------------------------
    @angular-devkit/architect       0.1402.10
    @angular-devkit/build-angular   15.0.0
    @angular-devkit/core            15.0.0
    @angular-devkit/schematics      15.0.0
    @schematics/angular             15.0.0
    rxjs                            6.6.0
    typescript                      4.8.4
```

**The Fix :**

> Update **angular.json** under **serve**

```
from:  "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:dev-server",
to: "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
```

Comment: It happens because of:
@angular-builders/custom-webpack
has dependence:

 "peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.0.0"
  },

Comment: Need to wait update from : @angular-builders/custom-webpack to support angular@xli 15 :(

Comment: Thanks! Im still struggling with this, have you been able to fix this?

Comment: https://github.com/just-jeb/angular-builders/issues/1312